# "Il y a" in complex verbal constructions

Tags: expressions

It is rather simple to say:

> **Il y a** for **There is** or **There are**
>
> **Il y avait** for **There was** or **There were**
>
> **Il y eut** for **There was** or **There were**
>
> **Il y aura** for **There will be**
>
> **Il y aurait** for **There would be**

But it's harder to use *il y a* with *les temps passés* as I don't have a logical model upon which to base my forming these verbal constructions.

As far as I can tell, these would be:

> **Il y a eu** for **There has been** or **There have been**
>
> **Il y avait eu** for **There had been**
>
> **Il y aura eu** for **There will have been**
>
> **Il y aurait eu** for **There would have been**

And now comes the most difficult part. How do I use *il y a* with *pouvoir* and *devoir* (what would be modal verbs in English) especially when used in the perfect tenses? How do I actually say:

> There can be...
>
> There could be...
>
> There can have been...
>
> There could have been...
>
> There must be...
>
> There must have been...
>
> There had to be...
>
> There had to have been...
>
> There will have to be...
>
> There will have to have been...
>
> There would have to be...
>
> There would have to have been...
>
> There should be...
>
> There should have been...

Comment: You conjugate the French verb *devoir* / *pouvoir* at whatever tense you need and *y avoir* remains static because the verbs that follows *devoir* and *pouvoir* are always followed by the infinitive. Il ne devrait pas y avoir grand chose de plus à dire.

Comment: Did you look in a dictionary, they're sometimes useful... [There must have been](http://context.reverso.net/traduction/anglais-francais/There+must+have+been), [There should have been](http://context.reverso.net/traduction/anglais-francais/There+should+have+been), etc.

Answer (score 1):

Personnellement, je traduirais ce que tu demandes comme suit:

There can be... : Il peut y avoir...

There could be...: Il pourrait y avoir...

There can have been...: Il peut y avoir eu...

There could have been...: Il aurait pu y avoir...

There must be...: Il doit y avoir...

There must have been...: Il doit y avoir eu...

There had to be...: Il devait y avoir...

There had to have been...: Il devait y avoir eu...

There will have to be...: Il faudra qu'il y ait...

There will have to have been...: Il faudra avoir été...

There would have to be...: Il faudrait qu'il y ait..

There would have to have been...: Il faudrait qu'il y ait eu...

There should be...: Il devrait y avoir...

There should have been...: Il aurait dû y avoir...